# Handling click within an SVG path in Angular

Tags: angular, svg

```
<div style="border: solid 1px red; height:666px; widt:444px">

  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
       width="8.26667in" height="11.6889in"
       viewBox="0 0 744 1052">
    <path (click)="oClick(5)" id="Selection #5"
          fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"
          d="M 506.00,167.00
           C 506.00,167.00 470.00,168.00 470.00,168.00
             470.00,168.00 398.00,168.00 398.00,168.00
             398.00,168.00 399.00,208.00 399.00,208.00
             399.00,208.00 435.00,208.00 435.00,208.00
             435.00,208.00 455.00,210.00 455.00,210.00
             455.00,210.00 507.00,210.00 507.00,210.00
             507.00,210.00 507.00,182.00 507.00,182.00
             507.00,182.00 506.00,167.00 506.00,167.00 Z" />
    <path (click)="onClick(4)" id="Selection #4"
          fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"
          d="M 514.00,168.00
           C 514.00,168.00 514.00,202.00 514.00,202.00
             513.99,204.74 514.31,208.38 512.40,210.57
             509.08,214.39 492.36,213.00 487.00,213.00
             487.00,213.00 455.00,213.00 455.00,213.00
             455.00,213.00 438.00,214.00 438.00,214.00
             438.00,214.00 398.00,214.00 398.00,214.00
             398.00,214.00 398.00,242.00 398.00,242.00
             398.00,242.00 394.00,242.00 394.00,242.00
             394.00,242.00 396.04,268.00 396.04,268.00
             396.04,268.00 396.04,278.00 396.04,278.00
             396.04,278.00 398.00,294.00 398.00,294.00
             398.03,297.11 397.46,305.15 399.17,307.47
             401.16,310.15 405.15,309.51 408.00,309.14
             408.00,309.14 427.00,309.14 427.00,309.14
             427.00,309.14 441.00,310.00 441.00,310.00
             441.00,310.00 457.00,310.00 457.00,310.00
             457.00,310.00 470.00,310.96 470.00,310.96
             470.00,310.96 489.00,309.00 489.00,309.00
             489.00,309.00 614.00,309.00 614.00,309.00
             614.00,309.00 614.00,273.00 614.00,273.00
             614.02,270.65 613.81,267.39 615.60,265.60
             617.89,263.31 625.74,264.00 629.00,264.00
             629.00,264.00 629.00,209.00 629.00,209.00
             629.00,209.00 614.00,209.00 614.00,209.00
             614.00,209.00 614.00,168.00 614.00,168.00
             614.00,168.00 581.00,168.00 581.00,168.00
             581.00,168.00 514.00,168.00 514.00,168.00 Z" />
  </svg>    
</div>
```

I snipped a few paths, but you get the picture

```
import {Component, ElementRef, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent {



  public onClick(roomNumber: number) : void {
    alert('Clicked ' + roomNumber);
}
```

However, `onClick()` is never called. What am I doing wrongly?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your html code.

`<path (click)="onClick(4)" id="Selection #4"`

In Angular, template variables must not be enclosed in id.
Changing the path code into this will solve your problem.

`<path (click)="onClick(4)" id="Selection" #4`

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vljltc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

In Demo, click on red Line from A to B will open alert

Comment: The click event works even if the #<number> is inside the id value. So, this had nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: @R.Richards No Bro. The click event will not work if #<number> is inside the id value. Property '<something>' does not exist on type 'Component. this error will be appeared.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jqulp7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: @R.Richards Check on Click Function in .ts file. onClick(roomNumber: number). The roomNumber type is a number so it's always working.  Check this example for more demonstrating that either #<number> work inside id value or not. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-njgib1

Comment: That looks like you are starting the id value with a #, and that is not what the OP is doing above.  *The OP is hard coding the value being passed to the onClick function and not trying to use a template variable for the value.*

Comment: You are correct (upvote) - I am hard coding the value, BUT, I am also generating the code programatically, I can change the HTML/SVG and just want to find a way to know that the user clicked path X

Comment: Also, I can handle clicking on a line, but not withing an enclosed path, like a square :-(

Answer (score 1):

Problem is onClick spelling is not correct in 1st path so click event is not working. <path (click)="oClick(5)" id="Selection #5" change to <path (click)="onClick(5)" id="Selection #5"
Can you please check this

Comment: Well spotted !! BUT, none of the others work :-(

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica Your code is working fine, onclick is calling and alert message is showing. I did following changes only. 
1- Increased stroke-width="200" so that it can click able.
2- onClick spelling corrected in 1st path.
3- Added ending cury braces in the end

Just cross check is the path correct inside styleUrls: 
Demo - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-smkj2r?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Thanks !  It's bedtime o'clock here, so I will have to get back to you tomorrow. Your code works for me - when clicking on a line - but not when clicking withing a closed path :-(  I will try more when i wake & let you know how it works out.

Answer (score 1):

I hate to post my own answer, as both of the others gave really good help.

However, the actual probalem was that I haveused `fill="none"` on my enclosed paths. When I changed that to `fill="white"`, where white is the background colo(u)r of my page, clicking suddeny worked.

If you want to know more, see [this page](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/05/svg-interaction-pointer-events-property/), search for the phrase "the entire circle can receive pointer events, but the area outside of the circle cannot" and look at the demo code, when you toggle the "fill".

Tl;dr - if you want to detect a click inside a path then you cannot use `fill="none"` on that path, you must give a fill colo(u)r.